# How do I create a populated dropdown list that will autofill form out according to which dropdown choice they make - taking from database

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

How do I create a populated dropdown list that will autofill form out according to which dropdown choice they make - taking from database

I am working on this and am very new to php but here is my code so far

```
$hostname="";
$username="";
$password="";
$database="";

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
//getFN();
function getFN(){

$query = "SELECT first FROM contacts";
$FNresult=mysql_query($query); 


$dropdown = "<select name='contacts' >";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($FNresult)) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['first']}'>{$row['first']}</option>";
  echo getLN();
  //$last .="\r\n<option value='{$row['last']}'>{$row['last']}</option>";
//echo $last;
}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;
}

//                  Get last name

function getLN(){
    $query = "SELECT last FROM contacts";
    $LNresult=mysql_query($query);

    $last;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($LNresult)) {

        $last = "{$row['last']}";

    }
    echo $last;
}//end getLN


mysql_close();
?>
<select name="fdsfd" onchange="document.getElementById('first').value = this.value">
<!-- <option value="<?//php echo $first; ?>"></option>-->

</select>


<form action="insert.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" id="first" value=""><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" id="mobile"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" id="fax"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email"><br>
Web: <input type="text" id="web"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What info will be autofilled? If this is standard information, not to substantial, and not sensitive personal information, I'd consider reading it all and control the autofill by Javascript. This solution will optimize performance at userside. 
If the autofill has a lot of possibilities, or will contain personal information, I'd handle this by POST calls. This will slow the perfomance a bit, since you need to handle the database calls, serverside. 
Would it be okay to ask, what you're programming? This would provide me with a better spectre of ideas, and therefor be able to help a little better.

/Pyracell

Comment: Programming a insurance form.....you select the company you have then it will access the phone # , ect... and fill in the forms below and then they just need to enter in there info thats required.

Comment: @user1578456 I'd say phonenumber is a personal information. I would set the onchange on your select, to invoke a javascript function. From this I would use AJAX-call to get the needed information from the database. This link has an okay tutorial in AJAX [link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript)